# Will accessing a Reference'd Entity cause a 'get()' for an already fetched Entity?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

```
class Parent:
    name = db.StringProperty()

class Child
    parent = db.ReferenceProperty (reference_class=Parent)

p = Parent.get()

q = Child.all()
q.filter ("parent =", p.key())
children = q.fetch(100)
children[0].parent.name # will this cause another call to get() on Parent ?
```

In the above example, will the accessing the parent.name attribute on one of the children cause a parent to be re-fetched - or all children's parent is point to 'p' ?

Hope this clear and appreciate any help..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will cause the parent to be refetched.

There is no implicit caching when using db.

ndb which does have caching, would potentially fetch the parent as you don't have a reference property and you need to perform an explicit get on a KeyProperty.

Comment: Thanks Tim ! Is it safe to do children[0].parent = p above, to avoid the fetch (in cases where the reference key is being used to fetch the Entity) ? I am guessing this will have other ramifications ?

Comment: In this case your just overwriting whatever is the in the current parent.  I would check first, I have a sneaking suspicion it may fetch the parent just by referencing parent. Have a read of nick johnson's article on prefetching referenceproperties, it shows you how to prevent a fetch occurring  (this is one of the big reasons I moved away from using db)  http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/ReferenceProperty-prefetching-in-App-Engine

Comment: Thanks a LOT Tim. This is what I was looking for. It seems the trick is to do a Child.parent.__set__ (children[0], p) (as opposed to 'children[0].parent = p'). Does that make sense ? (Also did you move to ndb from db then - how easy/difficult was the migration).